# How to read raw PCM data from file and convert to float?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, binaryfiles, pcm

I read a binary file of raw PCM data but cannot convert it to floats correctly. I am reading a raw pcm file that audacity recognizes as 16 bit unsigned. I am using the following code:

```
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(stream);
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);
uint8_t * buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
float * f = (float *)malloc(size * sizeof(float) / 2);

//read buffer
fread(buf, sizeof(uint8_t), size, stream);

//convert to float:
for(int j=0;j<size;j+=2){
  int16_t temp1 = buf[j] | buf[j+1] << 8;
  f[j/2]=(float)temp1/(float)32767.0;
  if( f[j/2] > 1 ) 
    f[j/2] = 1;
  if( f[j/2] < -1 ) 
    f[j/2] = -1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

j increments by 2 so you are only filling in every other value of f[].

Instead, assign f[j>>1]

Hopefully you allocated f to hold at least j/2 floats.

Comment: Thanks I added the allocation line and the right indices. Still the output isn't right (Only a hint of the original sound is hearable)

Comment: Assuming int on your machine is > 16 bits, then because you are shifting a unit8 you aren't sign extending and will never get any negative int's but rather erroneous positive ones.  You could consider using an int16 as the intermediate value instead of an int.

Comment: Great the sound is now better (used uint16_t as edited above) but still would this code cut off values or is it safe now?

Comment: No, not uint16, you need a **signed** type, int16, because you need the bit that you will shift into the MSB to be interpreted as a sign bit.  And no, if you do that right you should not need your clipping logic.